# Sort bins from pandas cut

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, cut

Using pandas [cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) I can define bins by providing the edges and pandas creates bins like `(a, b]`.

My question is how can I sort the bins (from the lowest to the highest)?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))

x1 = pd.Series(np.sign(np.random.randn(100)))
x2 = pd.cut(pd.Series(np.random.randn(100)), bins = [-3, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 3])

model = pd.concat([y, x1, x2], axis = 1, keys = ['Y', 'X1', 'X2'])
```

I have an intermediate result where the order of the bins is preserved

```
int_output = model.groupby(['X1', 'X2']).mean().unstack()
int_output.columns = int_output.columns.get_level_values(1)

X2    (-3, -0.5]  (-0.5, 0]  (0, 0.5]  (0.5, 3]
X1                                             
-1.0    0.101475  -0.344419 -0.482992 -0.015179
 1.0    0.249961   0.484757 -0.066383 -0.249414
```

But then I do other operations that arbitrarily changes the order of the bins:

```
output = pd.concat(int_output.to_dict('series'), axis = 1)

      (-0.5, 0]  (-3, -0.5]  (0, 0.5]  (0.5, 3]
X1                                             
-1.0  -0.344419    0.101475 -0.482992 -0.015179
 1.0   0.484757    0.249961 -0.066383 -0.249414
```

Now I would like to plot the data in a bar chart, but I want the bins to be sorted from the lowest (-3, -0.5] to the highest (0.5, 3].

I think I can achieve this by manipulating the string, using a split on "," and then cleaning brackets, but I would like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: I think your problem comes down to the intervals being represented as strings containing float values which are inherently difficult to sort. What about converting the intervals to python tuples? e.g. `import ast; x2 = x2.map(lambda r: ast.literal_eval(r.replace(']', ')')))`. This makes it really easy to sort them later on.

Comment: why is the original numeric ordering of the bins lost at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is main problem losing `ordered` [`CategoricalIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html).

```
np.random.seed(12456)
y = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100))
x1 = pd.Series(np.sign(np.random.randn(100)))
x2 = pd.cut(pd.Series(np.random.randn(100)), bins = [-3, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 3])

model = pd.concat([y, x1, x2], axis = 1, keys = ['Y', 'X1', 'X2'])
int_output = model.groupby(['X1', 'X2']).mean().unstack()
int_output.columns = int_output.columns.get_level_values(1)

print (int_output)
X2    (-3, -0.5]  (-0.5, 0]  (0, 0.5]  (0.5, 3]
X1                                             
-1.0    0.230060  -0.079266 -0.079834 -0.064455
 1.0   -0.451351   0.268688  0.020091 -0.280218

print (int_output.columns)
CategoricalIndex(['(-3, -0.5]', '(-0.5, 0]', '(0, 0.5]', '(0.5, 3]'], 
                 categories=['(-3, -0.5]', '(-0.5, 0]', '(0, 0.5]', '(0.5, 3]'], 
                 ordered=True, name='X2', dtype='category')

output = pd.concat(int_output.to_dict('series'), axis = 1)
print (output)
      (-0.5, 0]  (-3, -0.5]  (0, 0.5]  (0.5, 3]
X1                                             
-1.0  -0.079266    0.230060 -0.079834 -0.064455
 1.0   0.268688   -0.451351  0.020091 -0.280218

print (output.columns)
Index(['(-0.5, 0]', '(-3, -0.5]', '(0, 0.5]', '(0.5, 3]'], dtype='object')
```

One possible solution is [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) first number from `output.columns`, create helper Series and sort it. Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) original columns:

```
cat = output.columns.str.extract('\((.*),', expand=False).astype(float)
a = pd.Series(cat, index=output.columns).sort_values()
print (a)
(-3, -0.5]   -3.0
(-0.5, 0]    -0.5
(0, 0.5]      0.0
(0.5, 3]      0.5
dtype: float64

output = output.reindex(columns=a.index)
print (output)
      (-3, -0.5]  (-0.5, 0]  (0, 0.5]  (0.5, 3]
X1                                             
-1.0    0.230060  -0.079266 -0.079834 -0.064455
 1.0   -0.451351   0.268688  0.020091 -0.280218
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix to the problem you've highlighted above is to simply reorder the columns:

```
output[sorted(output.columns)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function to do so.

```
def dfsortbybins(df, col):
    """
    param df: pandas dataframe
    param col: name of column containing bins
    """
    d=dict(zip(bins,[float(s.split(',')[0].split('(')[1]) for s in bins]))
    df[f'{col} dfrankbybins']=df.apply(lambda x : d[x[col]] if not pd.isnull(x[col]) else x[col], axis=1)
    df=df.sort_values(f'{col} dfrankbybins').drop(f'{col} dfrankbybins',axis=1)
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another function. This worked for me, in multiple cases, unlike the other solutions. Figured I'd leave it here in a hope it will come handy for some people who come across the same issue in the future.

```
def sort_bins(bin_col):
    """
    Sorts bins after using pd.cut. Increasing order. Puts "NaN" bin at the beginning. 

    Input:
        bin_col: pd.series containing bins to be sorted

    """

    # Dictionary to store first value from each bin
    vals = {}

    # Iterate through all bins
    for i, item in enumerate(bin_col.unique()):

        # Check if bin is "nan", if yes, assign low value to put it at the beginning
        if item == "nan":
            vals[i] = -99999

        # If not "nan", get the first value from bin to sort later
        else:
            vals[i] = float(item.split(",")[0][1:])

    # Sort bins according to extracted first values
    ixs = list({k: v for k, v in \
                    sorted(vals.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}.keys())

    # Make sorted list of bins
    sorted_bins = bin_col.unique()[list(ixs)]

    return sorted_bins

# Example, assuming "age_bin" column has the bins:
sorted_bins = sort_bins(df["age_bin"])
```