# How do I plot dataframes iteratively as subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have 2 `for` loops in which I'm generating dataframes, and I need to plot them in subplots. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

count=1
nrows = 2
ncols = 3

for i in range(ncols):
    for j in range(nrows):
        data1 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}
        data2 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}
        data3 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])




        plt.subplot(ncols, nrows, count)

        # plot df1, df2 & df3 on the same same subplot with 3 different colors    
        ax = df1.plot(x='Col1',y='Col2')
        df2.plot(x='Col1',y='Col2',ax=ax)
        df3.plot(x='Col1',y='Col2',ax=ax)

        count +=1
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

It plotted 6 different blank subplots, but not in 3 columns and 2 rows like I wanted, and then plotted each of the plots below that on top of each other. So, we see only the last plot below the 6 blank subplots.

How do I get it to plot the 6 different plots on the 6 different subplots (in 2 rows and 3 columns)?

**EDIT:** I can get it to plot in the desired way with `plt.plot()` instead of `df.plot` as shown with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

count=1
nrows = 2
ncols = 3

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

for i in range(ncols):
    for j in range(nrows):
        data1 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}
        data2 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}
        data3 = {'Col1':['(-2.0, 1.0]', '(1.0, 4.0]', '(4.0, 6.0]', '(6.0, 9.0]', '(9.0, 11.0]', '(11.0, 14.0]', '(14.0, 16.0]', '(16.0, 19.0]', '(19.0, 21.0]', '(21.0, 24.0]'],
                'Col2':list(np.random.randn(10))}

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3, columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])




        plt.subplot(nrows,ncols,count)

        plt.plot([str(i) for i in df1.Col1], df1.Col2, 'o-')
        plt.plot([str(i) for i in df2.Col1], df2.Col2, 'd-')
        plt.plot([str(i) for i in df3.Col1], df3.Col2, 's-')

        plt.xticks(rotation=45)

        fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

        count +=1
```

[image]

But if you look carefully on the x-axes, the values are not in order. Meaning, the x-axes represent bins or ranges of something, and the last 3 bins should lie between bins 2 and 3 in the plots, in increasing order. In fact, it is in the proper order in `df1`, `df2` and `df3` if you print them out. But somehow, when plotting, it changes the order. So, how can I fix it?

**EDIT 2:** The data I put in the question is but a conjured example. In my real dataset, the `Col1` values for the dataframes are not all same. So, the x-axis values are different for each row of subplots. It looks something like this:

[image]

Therefore, in the code, the part until the 3 dataframes are defined must remain unchanged.

Comment: You'll want to use `pyplot.subplots` for this, and index into the returned numpy array of matplotlib `Axis` objects to access each individual subplot `Axis`. See: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: @PMende I did use `pyplot.subplot`, but not able to get the axes in sync. I also put in an edit in the question, where I show a way to do this, but the axes are not in order.

Comment: @Kristada673 I see. it looks as though the problem lies in losing the ordering of the binned categories. This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251277/sort-bins-from-pandas-cut